# Can a single Oracle block have rows for two different tables?

Tags: oracle

Oracle has logical blocks (basic unit) to store data. I want to ask can a single block have rows for two different tables?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it can. Tables belonging to the same cluster can have rows within same data block. This is the basic idea of the cluster. To keep the related data as close as possible. So if you make a logical join there is no work needed, the data is joined already. So both logical and physical IOs are reduced.

See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/tablecls.htm#CNCPT608.

Comment: Few types of table in oracle:

Ordinary (heap-organized) table.
Clustered table.
Index-organized table.
Partitioned table.

A single block can have rows for two clustered tables.
Only  clustered Table  share same block with another clustered table.

Comment: This is misleading. Clustered table and partitioned table are not true table types. Both are heap or index organized. Partitioned table just have multiple data segments. And tables within indexed cluster are still heap tables, they just share the cluster's index. And there can be more than two tables in a cluster so there can be rows from more than two tables in a single block.